# Selenium Webdriver AJAX - How to wait for the Request to Complete

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where I am not able to proceed further:

I have two buttons on the page (both the buttons are in the same frame). I'm using an `Iterator` for the `Button 1`. When we click the `Button 1`, it makes an AJAX call. I see a mouse loading animation for a second and then the product is added to the cart.

Say, if I have 5 buttons of the same type & want to click all the 5 buttons, when I use the iterator to click the 5 buttons, the control is going out of the loop instead of clicking the second button.

```
Iterator<WebElement> button1 = T2.iterator();
while(button1.hasNext()) {
    button1.next().click(); 
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}

driver.findElement(By.id("button2 id")).click();
```

If I use the `Thread.sleep()`, it's working fine. But I don't want to use that as its not the proper way.

The button2 id is also in enabled state, I wasn't able to use the [`Wait for the element to be enabled`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29). When the execution comes to the `button1.next().click()`, i,mediately it's going to the next line, without completing the loop. If i print some text after the `button1.next().click()`, the text gets printed 5 times. But don't know why the button is not clicked.

Even tried implicit wait, but no luck.

What is the best way to avoid such kind of issue?

Answer (score 7):

The proper way is to wait explicitly for the product to be added to the cart. Something changes on the page after the operation finishes, right? So wait for that change to occur! I don't know your webpage, obviously, but something along the lines:

```
// earlier
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.*;

// also earlier, if you want, but you can move it to the loop
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

Iterator<WebElement> button = T2.iterator();
while(button.hasNext()) {
    // find the current number of products in the cart
    String numberOfProductsInCart = driver.findElement(By.id("cartItems")).getText();
    button.next().click();
    // wait for the number of items in cart to change
    wait.until(not(textToBePresentInElement(By.id("cartItems"), numberOfProductsInCart)));
}
```

Comment: @VenkateshLakshmanan [If this answer proved to be useful and correct, consider accepting it. That way, future readers will know this question is resolved and that this answer is the correct and working one.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184794)

Comment: @VenkateshLakshmanan Could you please mark this answer as your accepted answer? (Click the checkmark to the left of the answer.)